# Format string as table in log txt file in PHP

Tags: php, string, logging

I'd like to write a .txt file of logs to keep track of transactions on a website written in PHP/Js.
I'd like for the string to be formatted in a tabular form.

Do you know how I can format a string like this using PHP?

I would expect to have for a given transaction something like this:

[image: table_log_txt]

Comment: You would need to start with some coding first and ask a more focused question.

Comment: I would also say that it might be better to just do it as a comma delimited format because then you can easily transfer the log to any excel spreadsheet program to view it and also filter/arrange the data